# pdfviewer doesnt open File

Tags: java, android, pdf-viewer

myfile.exists() return TRUE, however I couldn't open the pdf:

```
File myfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) 
        + File.separator + fileString ); //fileString=sample.pdf
Log.i("here", fileString + "---"+ myfile.exists());

pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfViewer);
pdfView.fromFile(myfile)
        .defaultPage(0)
        .spacing(2)
        .load();
```

I'm using this library for Pdf view in android.

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
```

If you wish, I can post all-working snippet code.

(using **pdfView.fromUri()** works fine but only once. My aim is to pick a .pdf from Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT once and save the uri of it for next usage.

Comment: "My aim is to pick a .pdf from Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT once and save the uri of it for next usage" -- use `takePersistableUriPermission()`: https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pdfView.fromFile(), I used pdfView.fromUri(),

```
pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfViewer);
//pdfView.fromFile(myfile)
pdfView.fromUri(Uri.parse(getIntent_uri))
    .defaultPage(0)
    .spacing(2)
    .load();
```

then after picking file, in onActivityResult() I used takePersistableUriPermission() for make the uri permanent accessible.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_PDF_FILE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        
        getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

special thanks to @CommonsWare